# module 'dropbox' has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, dropbox-api, attributeerror

I am trying to use the dropbox api with my python project but there seems to be an issue. I've installed the package with pip and everything was successful.

No errors when importing

```
>>> import dropbox
>>> client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient('auth_token_goes_here')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'dropbox' has no attribute 'client'
>>>
```

Comment: Did you call your file `dropbox.py`?

Comment: which version you are using, i see something different in the official documentation: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python

Comment: no my file is called send_files.py

Comment: Thanks for this, I was following a guide in a stackoverflow post, but this documentation was more helpful. @Aaron_ab

Comment: Yes, as Aaron pointed out, please refer to the official documentation. The code you're attempting to use is for a much older version of the library. The current versions doesn't have that attribute.